# MySQL Workbench Forward Engineer Relationship Tables

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship, forward-engineer

I used the Forward Engineer tool in the MySQL Workbench to generate a database based on the tables I entered. I was able to populate my tables, such as "Villagers," "Fish," and "Items" for the database I am building around the game Stardew Valley. However, when I linked the tables in the ER Diagram it created new tables based on relationships, such as Cooking_Has_Fish because many fish can be used in many recipes and many recipes can use many fish. But, once I populated the Cooking and Fish tables there was nothing in the generated Cooking_Has_Fish table. I am trying to understand how this table functions or how it can be used, or if it needs to be populated and I missed something.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No table ever gets populated on its own, you need to make sure that it gets populated. The third tables created for many-to-many relationships are called [associative or junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) and as a minimum contain the primary keys of the 2 tables they join.

If you have a `recipe_id` identifying recipies and a `fish_id` identifying fishes, then `Cooking_Has_Fish` table would have at least a `recipe_id` and a `fish_id` field.

If you want to associate `fish and chips` (with `recipe_id` 1) with `cod` (`fish_id` being 2), then you would do the following insert:

```
insert into Cooking_Has_Fish (`recipe_id`, `fish_id`) values (1,2)
```

This means the cod is required for the "fish and chips". You may add additional fields to your association table, such as how much cod you need for the fish and chips.

In summary: you have to populate your association tables based on how you would like to associate your entities (tables) that have many-to-many realationship with each other.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for your explanation. That makes sense. So if the association table only has id values is it better to add more fields, such as the name associate with the id? I am thinking that if I populate that table with only ids, then it will not be very helpful.

Comment: No, you should not add names, that are stored in the main tables and can be retrieved by joins. Probably you should read some books / tutorials on relational database design before proceeding any further because apparently you lack the basics. There is nothing wrong with this, we have all been there. But if you try to jump ahead without the basics, then you will only make a mess out of your databases.